# Can't include my files

Tags: php, include

I try to include my files, but for some reason I can't...

Here is my structure:
[image]

On `index.php`, there is a `include_once('includes/php/inc.php');`. The `inc.php` contains these lines:

```
// Required classes 
require_once '../classes/cl_calendar.php';
```

Perfect legitimate I think, but for some reason all I get is this error:

```
Warning: require_once(../classes/cl_calendar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /customers/xxx/xxx/httpd.www/new/extra/php/inc.php on line 14 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../classes/cl_calendar.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /customers/xxx/xxx/httpd.www/new/extra/php/inc.php on line 14
```

What makes this error to be displayed and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: The path is wrong of course. If your index.php is in the includes folder (where it should not be) then the correct path would be `classes/file.php`.

Comment: The `index.php` is not in the includes folder...

Comment: So, it's in the root. Well, then the correct path is `includes/classes/file.php`. Why the `..`? This would lead you one level over the root.

Comment: I include the `inc.php` file without the `..` no?

Comment: Oooh, I get what you mean! Please submit it as an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct path is includes/classes/file.php. Why the ..? This would lead you one level over the root.

The reason for that is that even though the relative relation of the two included files may be a different one, you're including it from the index file and therefore the path has to be relative to the index file.

Answer (score 1):

When you include a php file from another, it's just like taking the contents of that file and placing it in your initial (`index.php`) file.  So, when you to require more files from the `inc.php` file it's being based on the path of the initial file.  Try setting a base path in your `index.php` file and use that in your `inc.php` file. Try

```
// index.php
$base = "/var/www/htdocs/";  
// or something like dirname(__FILE__) if it may change
include_once($base.'includes/php/inc.php');

// inc.php
require_once($base.'classes/cl_calendar.php');
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. But when I try this, I get the following error `Warning: include_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/htdocs/includes/php/inc.php) is not within the allowed path(s):` followed by a whole list of files

Comment: Try setting it as a relative path, like `/`, or if you have in a subdirectory use `/sub/` e.g. and use the full path when including. `$base = '/'; require_once($base.'classes/cl_calendar.php');`

Comment: Try changing it to `$base = '/';` instead of `$base = "/var/www/htdocs/";`

Answer (score 0):

Just Drag and drop this page cl_calendar.php to your index.php page, and and this will showing as href link then just copy full href path and paste it as it is in include.

or try this one

```
require_once(/../classes/cl_calendar.php);
```